# Would reindexing latest record first be okay?

Tags: solr, sunspot

We reindex the whole database from time to time. It usually take hours. However only the latest ones show up at the front page. So I am thinking that, if I reindex the database backwards, that is, reindexing the records in the 'id desc' order first, I can reduce server down time by a lot.

However, from the performance point of view, would this be okay? Could it have a negative impact on the search time?

Comment: Are you doing a full indexing or delta indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have downtime at all?

If you commit at the end only you just will show the records only at the end when you do the commit (and order does not matter).

If you are doing soft-commits with maxDocs/maxTime set (Solr 4+) and reindex from the latest records then you will see those records almost immediately and the others will show up eventually.

I would recommend reading a bit on commit semantics and see if that will make things clearer.

Comment: By downtime I meant the time when nothing can be displayed. So you are saying there won't be any performance issue in reindexing backwards?

Comment: When do you have 'nothing' displayed? If I understood your scenario, you will have *old* records displayed until commit. Not 'nothing'. In any case, have a thorough look at soft-commits. It should be a very close match to your needs.

Comment: Nothing is displayed because old expired items are hidden in index page for my website logic. Full reindexing is done during major updates so solf-commits is irrelevant. I will mark this as answer because you say there won't be any performance impact for queries later on.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say that you are doing a full re-index, I would recommend indexing in a different core and make a swap. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5154919/326543) provides some references on how to make this happen.

In our setup, we have a Master/Slave setup, where indexing happens on Master and indices are replicated to Slaves. Slaves serve the search requests. This works out well in performance point of view.

Another thing you might want to consider - try and see why your indexing time runs into hours. In our case we realized that nested queries in DataImportHandler was the culprit, firing n+1 jdbc connections. We optimized it by creating a view, our indexing time went from 3 hours to less than 2 minutes!

Comment: Master/slave is indeed the proper way to handle it, but currently it is no possible for us.

Comment: You don't need master/slave strictly. Core swap can be done in a single instance as well. [The documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#SWAP) gives you a command that can do this.